# How to display a collection of results to a grid cell using jqGrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, json, jqgrid

I have a database containing many to many relations, so a Post can have multiple Tags, and a Tag can be assigned to multiple Posts

[image]

I am using jqgrid to display all the posts in a grid using the following code:

Javascript:

```
//grid
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    //post grid
    jQuery("#tablePosts").jqGrid({
        url: '/Admin/ListPosts/',
        datatype: 'json',
        mtype: 'GET',
        colNames: ['ID', 'Title', 'Short Description', 'Description', 'Category', 'Tags', 'Published', 'Posted Date', 'Modified Date', 'UrlSlug', 'Meta'],
        colModel: [
            { name: 'PostID', index: 'PostID', width: 50, stype: 'text' },
            { name: 'Title', index: 'Title', width: 150 },
            { name: 'ShortDescription', index: 'ShortDescription', width: 150, sortable: false },
            { name: 'Description', index: 'Description', width: 200, sortable: false },
            { name: 'Category', index: 'Category', width: 100 },
            { name: 'Tags', index: 'Tags', width: 100, sortable: false},
            { name: 'Published', index: 'Published', width: 80 },
            { name: 'PostedOn', index: 'PostedOn', width: 130 },
            { name: 'Modified', index: 'Modified', width: 130 },
            { name: 'UrlSlug', index: 'UrlSlug', width: 80, sortable: false },
            { name: 'Meta', index: 'Meta', width: 80, sortable: false }
        ],
        rowNum: 10,
        rowList: [5, 10, 20, 50],
        viewrecords: true,
        pager: '#pagerPosts',
        height: '100%',
        sortname: 'PostedOn',
        sortorder: "desc",
        //width to null && shrink to false so the width of the grid inherit parent and resizes with the parent
        width: null,
        shrinkToFit: false
    });
});
```

and this is my controller action:

```
public ActionResult ListPosts(string sidx, string sord, int page, int rows)
{
    int pageNo = page - 1;
    int pageSize = rows;

    //for paging
    int totalRecords = repository.TotalPosts(true) + repository.TotalPosts(false);
    int totalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling((float)totalRecords / (float)rows); //round up to smallest integral number greater than returned valued

    //for records
    var posts = repository.AllPosts(pageNo, pageSize, sidx, sord == "asc");

    var jsonData = new
    {
        total = totalPages,
        page = page,
        records = totalRecords,
        rows = (
            from post in posts
            select new
            {
                id = post.PostID,
                cell = new string[] {
                    post.PostID.ToString(), 
                    post.Title, 
                    post.ShortDescription, 
                    post.Description, 
                    post.Category.Name,
                    post.Tags.ToString(),
                    post.Published.ToString(), 
                    post.PostedOn.ToString(), 
                    post.Modified.ToString(), 
                    post.UrlSlug,
                    post.Meta
                }
            }).ToArray()
    };
    return Json(jsonData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

In my rows, I defined post tags as a string just to remove errors and I couldn't figure out how to display Tags as a list, and this is my grid:

[image]

as you can see, Tags column is not displaying Tag names, how do you display them correctly?

Comment: @Humayun - there's really no value in suggesting an edit just changing some code indentation, especially when the code looked fine as-is.

Comment: @DavidMakogon just reduced need of horizontal scroll a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insted of `post.Tags.ToString()` use `string.Join(",",post.Tags.Select(t => t.Name))`

Or pass array of tags to your view and use [custom formatter](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:custom_formatter)

Formatter may looks like this:

```
function tagFormatter(cellvalue, options, rowObject)
{
    var text = ""
    if (cellvalue.length > 0)
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < cellvalue.length; i++)
        {
            text += cellvalue[i].Name;
            if (i < cellvalue.length - 1)
            {
                text += ", ";
            }
        }
    }
    return text;
}
```

It will display comma-separated tags names;
And tag row:

```
{ name: 'Tags', index: 'Tags', width: 100, sortable: false, formatter: tagFormatter },
```

Is it helpful?

Comment: I tried your suggestion but the grid is not displaying anything anymore

Comment: Are you sure action `ListPosts` returns something?

Comment: If Tag is a string then everything is fine, once its an array, the grid becomes empty, does .ToArray() at the end of the select have an effect? because its like an array inside an array

Comment: Better idea;) Insted of `post.Tags.ToString()` use `string.Join(",",post.Tags.Select(t => t.Name))` and remove tag formatter from js. If it works i will edit my answer